# HPS bulb voltage vs ballast voltage

Tags: light-fixture, light-bulb

If I have a 1000W HPS ballast that runs 120v through 277V and an HPS bulb that is 1000W and has nominal voltage of 250V and nominal amps of 4.7 amps. Will this bulb work properly with this ballast?

Comment: I havent used HPS bulbs, but Googling, it would appear that it would work.

Answer (score 1):

HPS bulbs don't have a *voltage*, per se.  They need to be matched to the ballast that is driving them.  Welcome to the world of constant-current ballasts.

The HPS light, once the arc strikes, presents basically a dead short to the socket.  So it needs an external device to limit its current to spec, and that's the ballast.  Fluorescent, other HID, and LED all need the same thing, although the LED current/voltage curve isn't *that* steep and can be managed with a resistor.

The fact is, a light bulb that self-regulates to a constant voltage *is a most unusual thing*, even if we take it for granted.  That's why Edison's search was so difficult.  Edison really wanted to go with DC power.  (With AC power, ballasts are easy, and Tesla had fluorescent happening back then).

A 1000W HPS ballast will push 1000W worth of current through the bulb and that's that.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your bulb and ballast, and you'll see a code such as **S52** or **M57**, etc.  These are ANSI codes.

Nearly all high-output and specialty bulbs, ballasts, and fixtures will have an ANSI code designation somewhere on the device.  Sometimes it is integrated into the part number, and sometimes it stands alone, but if you deal with a lot of commercial/industrial/specialty lighting, you'll soon learn to recognize them.

The ANSI codes designate certain things about the bulb or ballast, such as the lamp makeup, wattage range, socket size, etc.  If the ANSI codes on a bulb and ballast match, you know they are designed to work together.

[image]

The bulb pictured above, for example, is an H38

[image]

And here's the matching ballast

Here's a blog post that explains it in more detail: [What is an ANSI code, etc.?](https://insights.regencysupply.com/what-is-an-ansi-code-and-how-can-you-use-it-to-select-the-right-hid-ballast-plus-other-hid-ballast-pairing-tips)